# A Multi-Line TextBox with Top Vertical Alignment

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, textbox

I'm trying to create a multi-line `TextBox` to allow the user to enter text.

I have:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0"
    Height="107"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="164,80,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="237"
    Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="300" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

However the text is centered vertically and I can't seem to find a `TextAlignment` property for vertical alignment.

I subsequently wrapped the textbox in a border and removed the `Height` specification, however when I click in the area below the textbox (but within the border) I would like the textbox to get focus and I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Has anyone come across this issue before and found a solution?

Comment: It's silly question, but have you tried to set the VerticalContentAlignment?

Comment: Hi Nick ! With this xaml only, I can't reproduce your issue. What version of .NET are you using ?

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix, thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for but failed to find. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it to give you the points!

Comment: @Nick it's ok. It does not answer second part of your question anyway ;)

Comment: try VerticalContentAlignment = stretch

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix, the second part of the question was only there because I didn't know about `VerticalContentAlignment`! Anyway - my problem is fixed now, so thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after discussion in comments. This is the Answer:

```
<TextBox Height="107"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
AcceptsReturn="True"
HorizontalAlignment="Left"
Margin="657,237,0,0"
VerticalAlignment="Top"
Width="237"
Text="Text alignment left and top" MaxLength="300" 
TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
```

No question should be left unanswered! :)